# How can I check the validity of the certificate in a p12 file in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pkcs#12

I am developing an application where I will need to check that uploaded p12 files have certificates that are issued out by trusted certificate authorities. I am trying to find a programmatic way to do it in javascript, though if it is impossible in js I can use a different language.

I don't know it's be most apt tool for this but I am using node's forge library and have the following:

```
const p12 = fs.readFileSync(PATH_TO_PDF_P12_CERTIFICATE, 'binary');
const p12Asn1 = forge.asn1.fromDer(p12, false);
const p12Parsed = forge.pkcs12.pkcs12FromAsn1(p12Asn1, false, 'password');
const bags = p12Parsed.getBags({bagType: forge.pki.oids.certBag});

const caStore = forge.pki.createCaStore();

forge.pki.verifyCertificateChain(caStore, [Object.values(bags)[0][0].cert]);
```

However, it seems like I the caStore doesn't have any certificates by default and I don't know how to get it to check the ones already installed on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

npm install p12-pem --save

import * as p12 from 'p12-pem';

/**
 * Given a p12 file, convert it to the PEM format.
 * @param {string} pathToCert The relative path to a p12 file.
 * @param {string} password of p12 / private key.
 */
const {pemKey, pemCertificate, commonName} = p12.getPemFromP12(certPath, password);
console.log('The converted private key in PEM:');
console.log(pemKey);

console.log('The converted certificate in PEM:');
console.log(pemCertificate)

console.log('The extracted commonName:');
console.log(commonName);

Source(S):
https://www.npmjs.com/package/p12-pem (AND>..) 
https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

Comment: Any luck with trying the install and import as suggested, Sahara?